# One form closed - second updates the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Writing an application on C#.
I have the opened Form1 with a button, that calls opening of Form2 by clicking. 
I want to make the following: when I close Form2, i want the DataGridView, which is an element of Form1, to refresh itself.
The question is not how to update the grid. 
The question is how to make a method which will notify the Form1 that Form2 is closed.
Thanks in advance!
That is the code for Form2. Code for Form1 is not necessary in that situation.

```
using System;`
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace cSharp_App
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myConnection = Form1.myConnection;
        string qry = "insert into pst.students_info (lastname,firstname,username,password,email) values ('" + this.lastname_txt.Text + "','" + this.firstname_txt.Text + "','" + this.username_txt.Text + "','" + this.password_txt.Text + "','" + this.email_txt.Text + "') ;";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmdInsert = new MySqlCommand(qry, myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = cmdInsert.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Пользователь добавлен");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }

    }



}
```

}`

Comment: There is already a method that notifies the closure of a form (well two to be precise). All you need to do is to catch that event from the Form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe to the `Form2`'s `FormClosed` event when you open it in the `Form1`.

```
Form frm = new Form2();
frm.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;
frm.Show();
```

And refresh the grid in the handler:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // refresh the gridview
}
```

Comment: The first passage should be written in the code of Form1, and second passage in Form2, right?

Comment: No, both code parts - in the `Form1`. No new code in the `Form2` needed.

Comment: Yeah.That works. Somehow it  takes two attempts to close the Form2, but  ithink i`m gonna manage that. Thanks!